# and operation on two binary numbers

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I want to perform a logical `and` operation on two binary numbers. I tried to use `bitand`, but that function can only be used for the `char` data type.

I want to perform `and` on two binary numbers. 
eg:

```
a=1101;
b=1010;
```

then the output of `a and b` must be

```
c=1000;
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
K=input('feed the value');
M=2^K;
S=input('feed the data');
disp(M);
s=dec2bin(S);
m=dec2bin(M-1);
q=bitand(s,m);
disp(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

> and i hav a prob that bitand is applicable only for data type char

That's wrong. `bitand` requires integer input arguments.

Example:

```
>> K=9

K =

     8

>> L=12

L =

    12

>> bitand(K,L)

ans =

     8
```

Comment: @chappjc: The problem is the `dec2bin` which outputs a char array.

Comment: Right I mean why was `dec2bin` in there at all.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string `s` to a binary vector using `s-'0'`. Do the same for `m`. Then you can apply [`and` (or `&`)](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html):

```
n = 4; %// specify number of bits
s = dec2bin(S,n)-'0';
m = dec2bin(M-1,n)-'0';
q = and(s,m); %// Or: q = s & m;
```

Or use [`de2bi`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html) (Communications toolbox), which directly converts a number to a binary vector:

```
n = 4; %// specify number of bits
s = de2bi(S,n,'left-msb');
m = de2bi(M-1,n,'left-msb');
q = and(s,m); %// Or: q = s & m;
```